# Azure DevOps release pipeline with special characters in a secret variable

Tags: devops, pipeline, special-characters

I have an Azure Devops pipeline in UI and has a secret variable with special characters like this,  my_pwd = N$D'"w(T+.,?&wi{;]

I am using the above secret variable in one of the override parameters like this "$(my_pwd)"

The pipeline has been failing with an error,
Unable to parse JSON error due to special characters.

How do I make it work?

Comment: Please can someone advise. Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: share your complete pipeline details, if using YAML paste the code as text in your question, if using classic UI paste a screenshot of it. Also add the complete details of the error you are getting

Comment: Hi @Sibtain, I am using classic UI and using the secret variable in one of the override parameters. It's failing as there are special characters in the variable.  How do I pass special characters in the variable?

Comment: Can you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77252480/edit) your post and tell all the relevant details?

Comment: Hi @Sibtain, edited the post

Comment: You need to add your pipeline details in the post and the error. Please make some effort and add all the details you have for the pipeline and the error, otherwise I doubt anyone would be able to answer your question.